# Consume WCF service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I can integrate the WCF service in xamarin with .net framework class library file. 
WCF - Developed in .net Framework 4.5
Xamarin - Developing in .net Core 2.2

Here I am unable to consume the WCF service created with .net framework. But I can consume the service where I as created the Asp.Net project with same .net framework version.

What need to do to consume it in xamarin

Comment: What have you tried so far in Xamarin? WCF services are just http or tcp endpoints.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf

Comment: Not the biggest fan of directly calling a WCF service from a mobile device! You might wanna add a Web-API layer or something

Answer (score 0):

Hi Colin / Jason / Hakim.....

there is no issue while consuming the WCF with ASP.net which was created both in the same framework. But unable to consume in Xamarin... Below is the code...

```
public class Class1
{
    public UserInfo GetUser(string username, string password)
    {
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);

        binding.Name = "WSHttpBinding_IService";
        binding.CloseTimeout = span;
        binding.OpenTimeout = span;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = span;
        binding.SendTimeout = span;
        binding.AllowCookies = false;
        binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        // binding.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
        binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        //binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        binding.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.Realm = string.Empty;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

        ICFService.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("..../Service.svc"));
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        return client.CheckUser(new UserRQ() { UserName = username, Password = password });
    }
}
```

Xamarin Button click

```
        try
        {
            APIServiceLibrary.Class1 api = new APIServiceLibrary.Class1();
            var user = api.GetUser(Entry_Username.Text, Entry_Password.Text);
            if (user != null)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```